# How to pass an array of vectors to a function in R

Tags: r

I create a function to compute an expression. I'm not sure how to pass vector of sub vectors into the function to calculate compute it with different inputs.
When I ran the code below, it return "numeric(0)" instead of 3 different values.

```
function_b <- function(x) {
  z = (x[1] ^ 2 + x[2] ^ 2) / (2 * x[1] * x[2])
  return(z)
}

v_2 <- c(c(1.1, 2.3), c(1.7, 5.2), c(6.23, 7.41))
function_b(v_2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R there is not index 0

```
function_b <- function(x) {
  z = (x[1] ^ 2 + x[2] ^ 2) / (2 * x[1] * x[2])
  return(z)
}

v_2 <- list(c(1.1, 2.3), c(1.7, 5.2), c(6.23, 7.41))
sapply(v_2,FUN = function_b)
[1] 1.284585 1.692873 1.015081
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly but may I know why we have to use sapply(v_2,FUN = function_b) instead of function_b(v_2) ?

Comment: @LouisTran this is not vectorized , so you need sapply .

Comment: In this case you can vectorize your function with `Vectorize`:  `v_function_b <- Vectorize(function_b); v_function_b(v_2)` outputs  `1.284585 1.692873 1.015081`.